# Sendmail for certain keywords in a console output

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I would like to receive an email if the Ubuntu console output of a long-running process contains certain keywords, e.g. if it reports the start and completion of certain processes.

I guess a combination of grep and sendmail could solve this in a pipe, but I still have too little experience. What kind of setup would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can keep firing `grep` the exact keywords on your `log` file in every `30 mins`(or a time interval you feel suitable).

```
result=`grep -e 'keyword1' -e 'keyword2' mylog.log` (or you can have individual greps for every keyword)
```

If it is found, then send out a email:

```
echo "Process completed!!" | mail -s "Process Status" someone@somewhere.com
```

You can club the above statements in a shell script as per your process's need . Let me know if this helps.